# How to hide columns when using "with" in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

How would I hide unwanted data for a cleaner response in laravel when using **with** statements.

For example, let's pretend I have a single post. That post has comments, and then comments have multiple tags related to each comment.

So I have below to illustrate the idea.

I have a model called **Post**
I then have a relationship in Post model that has comments relationship, ie

```
public function PostComments()
    {   
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post\Comments', 'postId', 'id');
    }
```

I also have a model called **PostComments**
I then have this relationship in there.

```
public function PostCommentsTags()
    {   
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Posts\PostCommentTags', 'postCommentId', 'id');
    
    }
```

Then in my controller I have

```
$post = Post::with(
            'PostComments',
            'PostComments.PostCommentsTags',
        )->first();
```

This works wonderfully, I get a response like this.

```
 {
        title: 'This is a title',
        description: 'Description',
        comments:[
            {
                id: 1,
                comment: 'this is a comment',
                commentTags:[{
                    id: 1,
                    tagName: 'emotion',
                    tagValue: 'angry',   
                },
                {   
                    id: 10,
                    tagName: 'timeOfDay',
                    tagValue: 'morning',   
                }],
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                comment: 'this is a comment too',
                commentTags:[{
                    id: 7,
                    tagName: 'emotion',
                    tagValue: 'happy',   
                },
                {   
                    id: 9,
                    tagName: 'timeOfDay',
                    tagValue: 'evening',   
                }],
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                comment: 'Too many comments now',
                commentTags:[{
                    id: 12,
                    tagName: 'emotion',
                    tagValue: 'angry',   
                },
                {   
                    id: 14,
                    tagName: 'timeOfDay',
                    tagValue: 'evning',   
                }],
            }

        ]
    }
```

But I want to get rid of a lot of clutter, ie **id**. (the real thing is a lot more complex than this example, so has a lot of clutter and unneeded info)

So I have this below, which hides all the **ids** for comments, this works great!

```
$post->Comments->makeHidden(["id"]);
```

But how do I hide it for **Comment tags** too? (I want no **ids** in my json)

I have tried below, but it does not work? How do you access nested models when using the with statement. I can't seem to find anything to help.

```
$post->Comments->CommentsTags->makeHidden(["id"]);
```

Spent a bit to much time on this now so time to ask for help. Please help :)

Best wishes.

Comment: you can use laravle resources  https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#main-content

Comment: Hello, so you want to be able to take some data from the relations. That is done this way (I will write a dummy and you make it work for yourself :) )


    ```Post::select(['id', 'title', 'body'])->with(['comments' => function($q) {
     $q->select(['id','comment_author','comment_body']);
    }])->get();```

Comment: @devsead all the comments work. Your and my example work for the level where comments is concerned. Your example does not work for "PostComments.PostCommentsTags" though. I get an empty array.

Comment: @Sprep hi there :) Yeah, it does not work for that but if you tweak it a bit it will work. One of the ways I usually do when need this is simply nesting. So, in with put comments.tags and then first `$q` will get comments and then inside of callback nest again to get tags too. Please try, if you fail, write here I will make it locally :)

Comment: @devsead lol I didnt use your exact example, I used the keys relevant to my situation. I tried this before I even posted this situation. If I just try to remove the id it breaks.

Comment: @devsead thanks for your help. I just had the aha moment.

Comment: @Sprep glad to see that you figgured it out. Is makeHidden laravel method or your custom? Does it pull the data and hides or doesnt pull? :D

Comment: @devsead makeHidden is a laravel method. You can have hidden in the model. But I might need that data in other parts of the app. However in this situation, I wanted to hide the ids, dates etc, to remove bloat out of the json. MakeHidden is a nice way to get rid of unwanted data when you use get() in a controller. Now I know how for nested relationships. (which is not easy to find)

Answer (score 0):

Argghh finally figured it out. If you want to remove unwanted data, you loop through it like this.

```
foreach($post->Comments as $comment){
    $comment->CommentsTags->makeHidden(['id','created_at','updated_at']);
}
```

I guess its a nice way to have hidden attributes without having it the model.